# scrollTop doesn't work on jQuery popup box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

This is my script for scrolling.

```
$("#oneA").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#twoA").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

and my html

```
<div id='oneA' style='height:100px;'></div>
<div id='twoA' style='height:100px;margin-top:300px'></div>
```

The above works fine as I tested on a static/normal page. But when I try the same on a popup box, it doesn't work at all. I suspect this could be library conflict between the popup and the jQuery scrolling.

I've placed these libraries

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>`

```
<script src='../js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js'></script>
<script src="../js/index.js"></script>
```

in the footer for the popup box. Without this the popup won't appear.What's the possible way to make the scrollTop work on this popup, please?

Comment: what do you mean "try the same on a popup box".. are these two divs buttons?  do you also have them in a pop up?.. the html and body can't scroll to top of #twoA when it's in a popup, you would need to pick an element on the page itself as your target.

Comment: @Maulzal, so it wont work on popup?

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#oneA").click(function() {
    $('#popupId').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#twoA").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

In the place of, `html,body` I replaced with the popupbox id and it worked within popup.